# R: Tabulations and insertions with data.table

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, data.table

I am trying to take a very large set of records with multiple indices, calculate an aggregate statistic on groups determined by a subset of the indices, and then insert that into every row in the table.  The issue here is that these are very large tables - over 10M rows each.

Code for reproducing the data is below.

The basic idea is that there are a set of indices, say ix1, ix2, ix3, ..., ixK.  Generally, I am choosing only a couple of them, say ix1 and ix2.  Then, I calculate an aggregation of all the rows with matching ix1 and ix2 values (over all combinations that appear), for a column called `val`.  To keep it simple, I'll focus on a sum.

I have tried the following methods

1. Via sparse matrices: convert the values to a coordinate list, i.e. (ix1, ix2, val), then create a sparseMatrix - this nicely sums up everything, and then I need only convert back from the sparse matrix representation to the coordinate list.  Speed: good, but it is doing more than is necessary and it doesn't generalize to higher dimensions (e.g. ix1, ix2, ix3) or more general functions than a sum.
2. Use of `lapply` and `split`: by creating a new index that is unique for all (ix1, ix2, ...) n-tuples, I can then use split and apply.  The bad thing here is that the unique index is converted by `split` into a factor, and this conversion is terribly time consuming.  Try `system({zz <- as.factor(1:10^7)})`.
3. I'm now trying `data.table`, via a command like `sumDT <- DT[,sum(val),by = c("ix1","ix2")]`.  However, I don't yet see how I can merge `sumDT` with `DT`, other than via something like `DT2 <- merge(DT, sumDT, by = c("ix1","ix2"))`

Is there a faster method for this data.table join than via the `merge` operation I've described?

[I've also tried `bigsplit` from the `bigtabulate` package, and some other methods.  Anything that converts to a factor is pretty much out - as far as I can tell, that conversion process is very slow.]

---

Code to generate data.  Naturally, it's better to try a smaller `N` to see that something works, but not all methods scale very well for `N` >> 1000.

```
N   <-  10^7
set.seed(2011)
ix1 <-  1 + floor(rexp(N, 0.01))
ix2 <-  1 + floor(rexp(N, 0.01))
ix3 <-  1 + floor(rexp(N, 0.01))
val <-  runif(N)

DF  <-  data.frame(ix1 = ix1, ix2 = ix2, ix3 = ix3, val = val)
DF  <- DF[order(DF[,1],DF[,2],DF[,3]),]
DT  <- as.data.table(DF)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's possible you'll find that doing the merge isn't so bad as long as your `key`s are properly set.

Let's setup the problem again:

```
N   <-  10^6      ## not 10^7 because RAM is tight right now
set.seed(2011)
ix1 <-  1 + floor(rexp(N, 0.01))
ix2 <-  1 + floor(rexp(N, 0.01))
ix3 <-  1 + floor(rexp(N, 0.01))
val <-  runif(N)
DT <- data.table(ix1=ix1, ix2=ix2, ix3=ix3, val=val, key=c("ix1", "ix2"))
```

Now you can calculate your summary stats

```
info <- DT[, list(summary=sum(val)), by=key(DT)]
```

And merge the columns "the data.table way", or just with `merge`

```
m1 <- DT[info]            ## the data.table way
m2 <- merge(DT, info)     ## if you're just used to merge
identical(m1, m2)
[1] TRUE
```

If either of those ways of merging is too slow, you can try a tricky way to build `info` at the cost of memory:

```
info2 <- DT[, list(summary=rep(sum(val), length(val))), by=key(DT)]
m3 <- transform(DT, summary=info2$summary)
identical(m1, m3)
[1] TRUE
```

Now let's see the timing:

```
#######################################################################
## Using data.table[ ... ] or merge
system.time(info <- DT[, list(summary=sum(val)), by=key(DT)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.203   0.024   0.232

system.time(DT[info])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.217   0.078   0.296

system.time(merge(DT, info))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.981   0.202   1.185

########################################################################
## Now the two parts of the last version done separately:
system.time(info2 <- DT[, list(summary=rep(sum(val), length(val))), by=key(DT)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.574   0.040   0.616 

system.time(transform(DT, summary=info2$summary))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.173   0.093   0.267
```

Or you can skip the intermediate `info` table building if the following doesn't seem too inscrutable for your tastes:

```
system.time(m5 <- DT[ DT[, list(summary=sum(val)), by=key(DT)] ])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.424   0.101   0.525 

identical(m5, m1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 This seems great.  One question: if I want to select different indices, e.g. ix2, ix3, and ix4, then I need to set a new key.  Is it okay to simply duplicate the data table with the different sets, store the keys, then, when merging, simply copy over the column I need to a reference/master data table?  It seems that creating keys takes a bit of time and I'd like to do that just once.  (I have a lot of RAM, so keeping overlapping DTs around is worthwhile if this makes things fast.)

Comment: You can try it both ways and see. If you are going to repeatedly run different aggregation statistics, maybe the duplication is worth it, but if you're just doing one pass in each grouping, then I guess it's a wash. To help do "one pass", also note that you can have arbitrary `j` expression, eg: `DT[, {calc1; calc2; list(out=calc1+calc2)}, by=...]`

Comment: Great point about arbitrary j.  I'll test key reuse and also follow up w/ Matthew Dyle if it seems keys can be reused.  Even better may be to figure out how to extract a keys object.  Btw, your example code sped up my calcs by 10X; if I can reuse keys, it'll be about 20X or better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about extracting a keys object ... consider coming over to the data.table help mailing list if you need more help (http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/mailman/listinfo/datatable-help), it might be a bit easier to brainstorm there.

Comment: Thanks Steve - the pointer to the mailing list is very helpful.  Also, my apologies - I was used to seeing Matthew's ID on SO, so I overlooked that it's a collaborative package.  Thanks to all of you for an excellent package.

Comment: No worries: Matthew is "the main brain" behind data.table, anyway. He's the guy who built the house -- in that regard, my contributions thus far are tantamount to just having swept the front stoop ;-)